# Get color tuple of colormap with manually set norms/limits?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I know it's possible to get the RGBA tuple for a scalar value for a given colormap by doing the following:

```py
from matplotlib import cm

rgba = cm.Blues(val)
print(rgba)
```

So I figured it would be easy to make a custom continuous color map, whose color mapping is zero  centered (0 corresponds to white) and whose positive values correspond to red colors and negative values correspond to blue colors. This has lead me to the following example code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

X = np.linspace(0,3,15)
C = np.random.uniform(-1,1,15)
Y = X+C

c = np.zeros((15,4))

for ind,val in enumerate(C):
    if val >= 0:
        c[ind] = cm.Blues(val)
    elif val < 0:
        c[ind] = cm.Reds(val)

plt.scatter(X,Y,c=c)
plt.show()
```

The problem is, that I don't know how to toggle the norms/clims of the color maps. How can I, essentially, do this:

```
cm.Reds(value=scalar,
        clims=(0,7.43))

cm.Blues(value=scalar,
         clims=(0,-3.32))
```

I will use the same absolute length of the scalar range for both Reds and Blues in my final code. I just wanted to show what I mean with my somewhat-pseudo-code. So yeah, how can I set custom norms of a cmap so I can get RGBA tuples from a scalar value, so that I can color code my scatter plots?

Comment: You cannot "set a norm of a cmap". Those are entirely different things. So step 1: Create a new colormap, step 2: create a norm. Then use norm and colormap in the scatter plot, like `plt.scatter(..., c=C, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)`.